# How to increase maximum response sizes in the new elastic java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to increase the maximum response size allowed when searching with the elastic 8.6 new(ish) java client, but I don't see the option anywhere.

The search looks like this

```
SearchResponse<MyClass> response = connector.getClient().search(s -> s
                        .index(connector.getIndexName())
                        .query(q -> q
                                .match(t -> t
                                        .field("whatever")
                                        .query(query)
                                )
                        )
                        .size(1000)
                MyClass.class
        );
```

And I found that there's a `RequestOptions` class which allows to set HTTP params, but I don't see anywhere how to plug it to the Request builder

```
var customOptionsBuilder = RequestOptions.DEFAULT.toBuilder();
        customOptionsBuilder.setHttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory(
                new HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory(MAX_HTTP_RESPONSE_SIZE)
        );

        this.customOptions = customOptionsBuilder.build();
```

I need to retrieve exactly 1000 results in one sitting, and the response sizes are just a little bit above 100MiB...